# Java Code Incorrectly Displaying in Webpage

Tags: java

I just uploaded a site to my schools server from my local host and something weird is happening.

http://helios.ite.gmu.edu/~ccarrin2/IT315/Assignment1/WebContent/index.jsp

This text

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c"uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

is displaying for some reason. However in the local host it did not. So now all of my jstl tags are not working and my conection with the servlet through the form is also not working. All i did was move the files over to the server and make the permisions for all of the files 755. I don't know if that was bad or good but that is what I have done so far. Any clue as to why this is happening and what I can do to fix it. And again, on the local host it does not display and all of the jstl code works great.

Comment: Looks like your JSP is not served by a JEE server. Which server is it?

Comment: Did you copy your web.xml file over also?

Comment: yes i did, and it is also at 755 permissions

Comment: and i also have the jstl jar under the lib folder. i just exported the zip right over so it's the same folders and files from the local host

Comment: Which servlet container does your school use? seems like the container isn't configured to serve ".jsp" files as JSP files.